# Mechanical / balance issues with War Priest feature replacement? [Attempt 3]

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, homebrew-review

I recently requested a review of a homebrew [War Priest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#WarDomain) feature [replacement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166220/mechanical-balance-issues-with-war-priest-feature-replacement-attempt-2) that contained major mechanical flaws (it could not be used at 1st level).

Below is revised wording that is intended to be useful at all levels:

> When you cast a spell on your turn by expending a spell slot, you may instead have the spell assume the level below the slot's (if valid) and use your reaction to make one weapon attack against a creature that was a target of the spell.
>
> Alternatively, when you cast a cantrip on your turn, you may choose to expend a spell slot and use your reaction to make one weapon attack against a creature that was a target of the cantrip.

My discussion in the [last post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166220/mechanical-balance-issues-with-war-priest-feature-replacement-attempt-2) is still relevant. Do you think there are mechanical or balance issues to this homebrew feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address this in parts. In terms of phrasing, you're a bit off from something I'd expect to see in officially published material. Try something like this:

> When you cast a spell that targets one or more creatures using a spell
>   slot of a higher level, you may use your reaction to make one weapon
>   attack against a creature that was a target of the spell. If you do, you cast the spell at one level lower than the expended slot.

That said, this is *really weird*. I'm not aware of any abilities (non-UA, anyway) that let you spend your reaction proactively like this. Much more common would be using a bonus action, a la Shield Master. But you don't want to use the bonus action, so we need to look for a different example. How 'bout College of Swords bard flourishes? That'd change the wording to something like this.

> Whenever you cast a spell on your turn that targets one or more
>   creatures using a spell slot, you may make one weapon attack against a
>   target of the spell as part of that action. If you do, cast the spell
>   one level lower than the expended slot, and you can't take reactions
>   until the start of your next turn. A spell's level must be lower than
>   the level of the expended slot in order to make use of this ability.

Still have the penalty, but without all the janky weirdness involved with using a reaction proactively. (This way is admittedly *slightly* better, since one could conceivably use their reaction *and then* make use of this ability, but that's an extreme case I don't think often enough to be worth extra verbiage.

And then the second half becomes again (no need for alternatively. This isn't an alternative -- it's a completely different situation):

> Whenever you cast a cantrip targeting one creature, you can expend one
>   spell slot to make a weapon attack against the target of that spell.
>   If you do, you can't take reactions until the start of your next turn.

Comment: Other than wording do you see any mechanical or balance issues with this change?

Comment: @SeriousBri - not really -- it's basically a different take on Divine Smite, but slightly worse damage-wise. Makes the war priest a little better at nova-ing if your spell is a damaging one -- but the reduction in spell level probably causes less damage than the attack (especially if it misses).

Comment: It's interesting that you bring up Blade Flourishes, since I based the reaction usage on Mobile Flourish. The relevant wording I see on D&D Beyond is: "Whenever you take the Attack action on your turn... if a weapon attack that you make as part of this action hits a creature, you can use [Mobile Flourish to]... push the target up to 5 feet away from you... You can then immediately use your reaction to move up to your walking speed to an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the target."

Comment: An issue with the "cannot use reactions" wording is that a cleric could make two weapon attacks with this feature by casting e.g. a cantrip with their action and a spell with their bonus action. Whether or not that is acceptable is a balance question.